# PHP and SQL getting latest entry in DB from DateTime

Tags: php, sql, json

I have a database which id,title,subject and datetime and I'm calling a php page that takes in a request from clients to show the latest entry in the db from the difference of time from the client and checks with the last entry's datetime. PHP code as follows

```
    $date = "2012-10-06 18:13:52";

//Establish a connection
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost','regadmin','regadmin');

//Select the mySQL db
$db = mysql_select_db('easy_comm', $conn);

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT `title`, `subject`,`date_sent` FROM `books` WHERE  `date_sent` > '$date'", $conn);
$count=mysql_num_rows($sql);

if($count != 0){
    $json = array('boolean' => true);
}
else{
    $json = array('boolean' => false);
    //echo "No record";
}
```

From the above code and the provided $date variable, it will always return true and the last entry is
     2012-10-06 18:10:52

I have tried converting to UNIXTIMESTAMP but same problem

Comment: which type of value you are using in your database?`timestamp`or `date`

Comment: I don't see a problem. 2012-10-06 > 2012-10-04, so it should return true.

Comment: Don't use the mysql_* functions, they're deprecated in all but name.  Use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: Barmar but I want precision down to time in the time stamp and in some situations it's suppose to return false *edited* oops I didn't realize the typo date above will change it. But nonetheless, problem persists

Answer (score 0):

Well this works good enough for me.Please make sure the column against which you are comparing the date surely happens to be `DATETIME` column not a `VARCHAR` or something else.
Please post us database structure to see the collation as well and also try printing the query on the fly and then execute in your console.